# Console output of nth element array

Tags: java, arrays

i've got an array with n element and i'm trying to set the values ​​my array, so that each element has its value as Positon.

I.e. the first element at position 0 is 0, the second element is at position 1 to 1, etc., up to the n-th element at position n-1 with the value of n-1.

And finally i will give the contents of my array on the console.

Well i already set the values correct i think, but i can't show on the console.For example how i can show the the position "n-1" has the value "n-1" ?

Here what i did so far:

```
  public void exercise1(Integer n){

   int[] arrayA = new int[n];

   int counter;

    for(counter=0; counter<arrayA.length; counter++){

              arrayA[counter]=counter;
                         }
    }
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Yeah but how ?
Ok i can put System.out.println(arrayA). It doesn't work.

Comment: first step - [google](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=java+how+to+output+array&aq=f&oq=java+how+to+output+array&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j62l3.10780&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

Use System.out.println and this code:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.    toString(your_array_name_here));
```

Comment: Where should put this statement ??

Comment: @Tiro After you have set the values of the array. This line will print it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your loop

```
System.out.println(arrayA[counter]);
```

Comment: did you check the console output?

Comment: When i click i get nothing ;(

Comment: What about this: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arrayA[counter]);

Comment: He specifically asked for console output not GUI output.

Answer (score 0):

i think what Hélio Santos says it's true and it's works for me :

`public class koponk {`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    exercise1(10);
}

public static void exercise1(Integer n) {
    int[] arrayA = new int[n];
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < arrayA.length; counter++) {
        arrayA[counter] = counter;
        System.out.print(arrayA[counter] + " ");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class apples{


public static void main(String[] args) {



    exercise(4);

}

   public void exercise(Integer n){



    int[] arrayA = new int[n];

    int counter;

    for(counter=0; counter<arrayA.length; counter++){

        arrayA[counter]=counter;
    }

    System.out.print("[");

    for(counter=0; counter<arrayA.length; counter++){

        if(counter == n-1){

         System.out.print(arrayA[counter]);   

        }else{


          System.out.print(arrayA[counter] + ", ");

       }
    } 
    System.out.println("]");





}
```

}

Well guys, i did something like that after your advicesand  it works. Thank you very much:)